# Htmx trigger when datalist option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

I have an input with a datalist in a django template.
Right now it has a keyup delays trigger to fill the datalist, basically a search as you type.

```
<input list="users_list" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username"
       id="user_search_bar"
       value=""
       hx-trigger="keyup delay:500ms"
       hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'
       hx-post="{% url 'user_search' %}"
       hx-target="#users_list">
<datalist id="users_list">
       <option data-value="{{id}}" value="{{elem}}">{{element}}</option>
       <!--...-->
</datalist>
```

Is it possible to know when a datalist option was selected/typed and have a htmx trigger for that?
I have searched the htmx documentation and did not find anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an option is selected from the datalist, it will trigger a `change` event in the input element. You can change your code to `hx-trigger="change"`.

```
<input list="users_list" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username"
   id="user_search_bar"
   value=""
   hx-trigger="change"
   hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'
   hx-post="{% url 'user_search' %}"
   hx-target="#users_list">
```

Comment: Ok I was using the Microsoft Edge and that works in there, but when I use Firefox the behavior changes. For example when I click in an element of the datalist on the Edge, the change trigger is detected, but on firefox is not detected. On firefox the change trigger is detected only when I take the cursor out of the input.

Comment: Try using "input" instead of "keyup" and change it as in the example I gave you in your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75617392/multiple-targets-for-htmx/75617891#75617891